# How to avoid 'IndexError: list index out of range' error?

Tags: python

Suppose there are a list called '`my_list`' and an int variable called '`list_index`'. Basically, the list '`my_list`' might change over time and hence the '`list_index`' might raise '`IndexError: list index out of range`'. However, I just want to make record when this error occurs since it is not that important. To avoid this error, my basic solutions currently are:

```
# My first way
if my_list[list_index: list_index +1]: 
    print('item exists')
else:
    print('item does not exist')

# My second way
if -len(my_list) <= list_index < len(my_list):
    print('item exists')
else:
    print('item does not exist')
```

Except for `try/except` statement, are there other solutions to avoid the 'IndexError: list index out of range' error?

Comment: The Pythonic way is to wrap the statement in a try-except.

Comment: In Python the concept [EAFP](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-eafp) is mainly used... "It's easier to ask for forgiveness than for permission."... Look at [Exception Handling](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#the-try-statement) in Python

Comment: What is the motivation behind this question/what issue are you trying to solve? Perhaps there's a better way to do it.

Comment: Assuming you want to allow negatie indices, as your second approach suggests: Your first will not work for `-1`, as `[-1:0]` is `[]`. I'd go with the comparison chaining with `len` or try/except.

Comment: If you don't like `try/except` but think your comparison chaining is too long, how about this gem: `abs(int(-i-0.1)) < len(l)`

Comment: @tobias_k you are right. The first way has a bug when the list index is -1.

Comment: Why do you have a `list_index`? What’s the full context here?

Comment: One may want to just check `len(my_list)`

Answer (score 18):

You can use a try-except.

```
a = [1,2,3]

try:
  print(a[4])
except IndexError:
  pass
```

Answer (score 3):

What we can do in this scenario is we know a possible error can happen, so we encapsulate the statements where the error is prone to happen inside `try` and we add an `except` block with an error type where we define what the program should do if it encounters that error.

The general syntax for it is,

```
try:
    # statements that can possibly cause an error
except error_type:
    # what to do if an error occurred
```

So here the error you are mentioning is `IndexError` which catches the out of index exception in runtime. So a neat and pythonic way to do it is as follows.

```
try:
    index_value = my_list[list_index]
except IndexError:
    index_value = -1
    print('Item index does not exist')
```

Answer (score 3):

Use **range(len(LIST)-1)**:

```
for i in range(len(LIST)-1):
        if LIST[i] < LIST[i+1]:
            ... # you got an idea; no index error since range(len(LIST)-1)
```

Answer (score 0):

actually you don't need to catch it, you need to avoid it by using following construction:

```
my_list = [1, 2, 3, 4]
for i in range(0, len(my_list)):
    print(my_list[i])
```

len(my_list) - will prevent you to access to item that doesn't exist

Comment: You can further simplify this as:

for i in range(len(my_list)):